# Search in Start menu is working but does not display any characters

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

If I press the Start button I can see the Start menu as it was before.

But if I point the mouse at the search string the cursor doesn't change it self from arrow to text cursor. If I start to print there's no chars appearing but the search actually takes place!

Something broke up? Is there any possibility to repair?

Comment: Try typing something in & then selecting what you've typed with the mouse.  This should show the text if the problem is because of a color being mis-set so that you can't see text against the background.

Comment: @Debra nothing visible even after I selected the text :(

Comment: Maybe the echo is delayed;  try pasting in text that you have copied from an app like Notepad.  Also right-click the desktop, choose "Personalize", go to Window Color > Advanced Appearance settings, and check/change the color for the Message Box font (click near the "Message Text" to bring that option up).